# problem with displaying the Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

HI

I am trying to get the view using the following:

```
$this->getView()->form = $form;
```

but still I do not get the form design viewed
I cross checked for form design with this code

```
include_once 'Zend/View.php';
$view = new Zend_View;
$form->setView($view);
echo $form;
```

and it worked
so plz let me know how can I get the design displayed using this :

```
$this->getView()->form = $form;
```

Regards
kiran

Answer (score 0):

Where are you trying this code?

What is the context?

If you're trying to use Zend_Form as a standalone component, you **must** set manually the view object, it's what you do with `$form->setView(new Zend_View());`, however, if you use the classic MVC implantation of Zend Framework, the view object will be loaded using the one defined by your application.

So be sure to have either a view object initialized in your `Bootstrap.php` or in your `config.ini`

Comment: How to define view object for mvc implementation of zend framework?

Comment: The simplest way is to use the [application resource](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html#zend.application.available-resources.view)

Comment: @Boris..thanks i am using this code in Authcontroller.php..and i used $form->setView(new Zend_View()); this one also but not displaying the form.. if give echo $form->setView(new Zend_View()); its showing the form.